# Android App - AndroidManifest.xml does not work

Tags: android, html, xml

there always comes the massage **The < receiver > element must be a direct child of the < application > element**. Does anyone no the correct code? I want to ad LeadBolt ADS. But it's a little bit harder than I thought haha.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testmoney"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testmoney.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.<sdpackagename>.ReEngagementService" >
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.<sdkpackagename>.AdBootReceiverService" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="<sdkpackagename>.ReEngagement" >
        <receiver android:name="<com.example.testmoney>.BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        </receiver>

     </application>
```

Comment: You're receivers are nested. They cannot be nested (one inside the other).

Answer (score 1):

The correct manifest is (you've placed closing tag to the incorrect place, and please also make sure to replace `<sdkpackagename>` with a valid name):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testmoney"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testmoney.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.<sdpackagename>.ReEngagementService">
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.<sdkpackagename>.AdBootReceiverService">
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.<sdkpackagename>.ReEngagement">
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.testmoney.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


     </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank You! Do I have to replace all < sdkpackagename > with com.example.testmoney.MainActivity ?

Comment: if these is stuff implemented in your app, than you should use `com.example.testmoney.ReEngagementService`, `com.example.testmoney.AdBootReceiverService` and `com.example.testmoney.ReEngagement` as a name

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is these four lines:

```
    <service android:name="com.&lt;sdpackagename>.ReEngagementService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.&lt;sdkpackagename>.AdBootReceiverService" >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="&lt;sdkpackagename>.ReEngagement" >
    <receiver android:name="&lt;com.example.testmoney>.BootReceiver" >
```

Remove the `&lt;` and first `>` in each line and it should work.

EDIT: Try this

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testmoney.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.<sdpackagename>.ReEngagementService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.<sdkpackagename>.AdBootReceiverService" >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="<sdkpackagename>.ReEngagement" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="<com.example.testmoney>.BootReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


 </application>
```

Comment: That was a mistake. I have > in my code. But the massage The < receiver > element must be a direct child of the < application > element still appears.

And if I remove and < and > aswell the message STILL appears ._.

Comment: @user3420083 you aren't closing the `receiver`